# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" When I send html through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an iframe which is editable to be used as post input for a blog.
I'm using jQuery to retrieve the html from the body of the iframe:

```
function sharePost (feedNumber)
{
  var postBox = $("#ifrNewPost" + feedNumber).contents(); // Gets iframe content
  var postContent = $('body', postBox).html(); // Gets iframe body

  var params = { post: encodeURI(postContent) };

  // Send to server
  $.ajax({

    type:'POST', 
    url: 'script/post.php', 
    data: params, 

    success: function(response) {
      $(document).append(response);
    }

  });
}
```

Nearly works perfectly, my problem is that when I paste something into the iframe, there seems to be a newline added to the start of what I paste, then when submitted, the script is failing with:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

I have tried encodeURI and encodeURIComponent to no avail. When I view the code of the page after pasting there are no apparent changes to what I paste, it just appears to have a new line added before it. Any solutions on how to send the HTML safely through to my php script?

Comment: I don't think `$('body', postBox).html();` is valid.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Chrome usually gives better detail as to *where* the error lies.

Comment: Chrome says jquery.js:614 so it must be something in the html which is causing an error. If I don't paste, the data is sent through fine, do you have a more reliable way to get the body data?

Comment: Oh, and it does the same thing if I get it using .text()

Comment: You're trying to get the contents of an iframe via jQuery?

Comment: That's right, an editable one

Comment: Have you tried [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)?

Comment: Yep, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Comment: I apologize, I didn't even see it there in your code.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do cross-site-scripting (XSS) which is sort of frowned upon. Why not display this content in a `<div>` instead?

Comment: Oh yep, I already use that to get the contents of the iframe, the iframes have id's like "ifrNewPost1" and "ifrNewPost2", then there are buttons above each which have an onClick="sharePost(1)" substituting the 1 for the id number of the ifrNewPost

Comment: I'm just trying to make a rich text editor for my website, I've seen it done with iframes elsewhere?

Comment: Dude, there are *free, open-source* WYSIWYG editors out there. Why not just implement one? You're re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: I like learning how to do this stuff for a start :P plus it didn't seem  like that much of a challenge, this is the only thing wrong with it so far. I tried one but couldn't get it to fit with my design, can you recommend one that can simply replace the iframe while the buttons I've designed already can be used to trigger the editors functionality?

Comment: Oh and the only functionality I really need is adding images, which I've already done, and writing text. Well, that's for now anyway, I will probably want to add other functionality later.

Comment: And the problem only seems to occur on chrome so far. Everything seems to be in order with IE9 and Firefox

Comment: :-/ I feel bad I can't really help from here. Maybe if I had the code in front of me I could do something for you, but that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: I'm sure I'll figure it out some how. Perhaps change newline characters into <br />'s will work.

Comment: Changed the iframe to a textarea, the same thing was happening when I added a line break, after a little tinkering I managed to convert the newline characters to <br />. Everything seems to work fine now! Thanks for attempting to solve it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with what the php code was returning after all!
Simply running a regex to change any newlines to br's did the job!

```
$post = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", "<br />", $post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

```
$post = nl2br($post);
```